# How to display the store name in the shopping cart?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-comments

I have a site with Drupal 8.6 and Commerce 2.11

I have several stores belonging to different owners (maketplace).

When a customer how in 2 stores, this will create 2 shopping carts.

How to display above the shopping carts, the name of the store?

I created the 4 files below in a custom module.

**My problem :**

An authenticated user adds products to his shopping cart, he has a 403 error when he goes to the shopping cart page.

I checked the permissions and they are correctly set.

If I uninstall my custom module, the shopping cart is accessible again.

Why ?

`commerce_marketplace_cart.info.yml` :

```
name: Commerce Marketplace Cart
description: Implements Commerce Marketplace Cart.
type: module
core: 8.x
package: Commerce (contrib)
dependencies:
  - commerce:commerce_cart
  - commerce:commerce_product
```

`commerce_marketplace_cart.module` :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Commerce Marketplace Cart.
 */
```

`commerce_marketplace_cart.routing.yml` :

```
commerce_cart.page:
  path: '/cart'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\commerce_marketplace_cart\Controller\MarketplaceCartController::cartPage'
    _title: 'Shopping carts'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access cart'
```

In the folder `/src/Controller` there is the file `MarketplaceCartController.php` :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_marketplace_cart\Controller;

use Drupal\commerce_cart\Controller\CartController;

/**
 * Overrides the cart page controller.
 */
class MarketplaceCartController extends CartController {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function cartPage() {
    $build = parent::cartPage();
    $carts = $this->cartProvider->getCarts();
    $carts = array_filter($carts, function ($cart) {
      /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $cart */
      return $cart->hasItems();
    });

    if (!isset($build['empty'])) {
      foreach ($build as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value['#prefix'])) {
          $store_name = $carts[$key]->getStore()->getName();
          $build[$key]['#prefix'] = "<h2 class='cart cart-store-name'>{$store_name}</h2>" . $value['#prefix'];
        }
      }
    }

    return $build;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a permission called access_cart. Define this permission in a permission.yml file and assign this permission to the user.

Comment: All users must have access to the cart. Can the authorization be deleted?

Comment: Add permission access content it is a general one.

Comment: what exactly should I do? I do not know how to do that. Should he create a new file? In which folder? Thank you

Comment: commerce_marketplace_cart.routing.yml is this your custom file? If yes change requirements:
    _permission: 'access cart' to 'access content'

Comment: Do you know the name of the permission to access the products?

Comment: access content is generally used permission to give access and it is available for all users.